# Comet Chat Issue: Please help me

Tags: livechat

I am very frustrate, i implemented comet chat with codeigniter, its working almost as expected but i still have some problems and need to rectify soon. Problem listed below.

1 When i logged in with 2-3 users in different browsers, it randomly change their status "Offline" and "Online", don't know why? however all the users are online.

2 Sometimes when i logged in with the site, cometchat bar at bottom shows only the text "Offline" means "0 online users" and once i clicked on the cometchat bar then it start displaying the actual status and count of the users.

3 I've noticed that the "page translation" feature of comet chat doesn't seem to work for IE browser but ok for google chrome. Can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

1)check wheter the last activity column in the users table is changing properly

2)getuser() function in integration.php is returning a value

3) i have to check it